# Cast error in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, casting, int

I have a function in a class "Checkout" that runs a sql statement to insert a record into a table, then select the scope_identity, giving me the ID of that record. It returns the ID as an int, and I assign it to a variable in the webpage:

```
int OrderID = Checkout.WriteOrder_tblOrders(CustID);
```

Here's the function:

```
public static int WriteOrder_tblOrders(int CustID)
{
    // OrderID is initially 0, then changed when scope_identity is called in the sql statement.
    int OrderID = 0;
    DateTime OrderDate = DateTime.Now;
    string sql = "INSERT INTO tblOrders (OrderDate, CustID) VALUES (@OrderDate, @CustID); SELECT scope_identity();";

    using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, myConnection))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustID", CustID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderDate", OrderDate);
            myConnection.Open();
            OrderID = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            myConnection.Close();
        }
    }
    return OrderID;
}
```

The debugger shows that there's nothing wrong with the function, and new records are showing up correctly in that table, but I'm getting an

> "Invalid Cast"

error on the first line, where I assign OrderID. I've tried this:

```
int OrderID = (int)Checkout.WriteOrder_tblOrders(CustID);
```

With both int and Int32, and also tried using Convert.ToInt32, which didn't work either. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What data type does the SQLCommand method ExecuteScalar() return?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964305/what-data-type-does-the-sqlcommand-method-executescalar-return)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason may be you are getting null values.
So you ca create an extension method as follows

```
public static T ExecuteNullableScalar<T>(this SqlCommand cmd) where T : struct
{
    var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    if (result == DBNull.Value) return default(T);
    return (T)result;
}
```

Usage becomes:

```
int value = cmd.ExecuteNullableScalar<int>();
//new approach
ulong value=cmd.ExecuteNullableScalar<ulong>();
```

### Other-Wise

```
 myConnection.Open();
 var o = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
 OrderID = (o== DBNull.Value ? 0 :  Convert.ToUInt64(o));
 myConnection.Close();
```

### changed

```
OrderID = (o== DBNull.Value ? 0 :  Convert.ToUInt64(o));
```

Comment: so it should be cast in `ToInt64` or `ulong`?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help guys, didn't realize that scope_identity returns a decimal. I altered the code like this:

```
OrderID = Convert.ToInt32((decimal)cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

It now works fine. Thanks!

Comment: Here's an article explaining it a bit more FYI:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601620/why-does-select-scope-identity-return-a-decimal-instead-of-an-integer